# Mapping JSON String as Postgresql's JSON type with hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

How should I tell Hibernate to map a String containing a JSON value to PostgreSQL as PostgreSQL's [JSON Type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-json.html) ? Assume I have an attribute like this:

```
private String foo_json_value;
```

I have used Gson to convert `Foo` object to a JSON String and now I want to store this attribute in PostgreSQL. I have learned that PostgreSQL has a [JSON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-json.html) data type, so I want to use this datatype instead of string (varchar). What JPA annotation or mapping strategy should I use to be able to store this String as JSON directly?

Comment: This has been discussed here before; recommend searching for related questions.

Comment: @CraigRinger where? i couldnt find this specific case.